# Recurring Payments API on Dwolla

Tags: dwolla

Just running through the API to see if I can use Dwolla for web apps that require recursive billing - there is no API support for this, is there?

Thanks!

Comment: In fact - this seems to be a fairly common question among developers. Much conversation surrounding the needed use of a Pin # if we are to automatically charge without the direct consent of a user. Obviously there many facets in this question. I have 3 or 4 projects that all seem very well of the "DWOLLA" mindset, but i'm not sure I can provide what they need without an API for recursive billing.

Comment: Conversation was left off at: https://getsatisfaction.com/dwolla/topics/delayed_waiting_period_escrow_payments Where it was marked 'planned' 10 months ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eric is correct. We're definitely planning to add an API for recurring/scheduled payments, but that won't happen until the release of our API V3, which will happen closer to the end of the year...

We are, however, about to remove the PIN requirement for the request money method, and so depending on your flow, this might help somewhat.

Comment: No kidding? Well, this would change everything. So what will be the flow without a Pin for the request of Money - and any ideas what the timeliness of "about" may be? Thanks for answering these questions guys.

Comment: Just happened today. We've deployed the changes, and among other great changes, PINs are no longer required for requesting money. Checkout the announcement blog post - http://blog.dwolla.com/major-api-updates/

Comment: And just so I am crystal clear - there is no way to automatically charge someones account. They will stil need to login to Dwolla and approve the request transaction, correct? Essentially I am trying to have a recurring billing system which, once they setup, will not need further attention from them every month.

Answer (score 3):

Michael- you mention above recurring was going to be added to the v3 API release.

- Has this been delayed?

Also I sent a email to your posted email address between Dec25 and Jan.1 and didn't rcv a reply to a previous post on the endpoints for the Funding sources.

- Did you rcv this private email concerning Clay Gulick's questions on GetSatisfaction?

These Funding source API's still seem to have lots of questions around them from the developer community and not much documentation on how to chain FORM processes with the oauth Token from REGISTER to FUNDINGSOURCE BANKACCOUNT ENDPOINTS

Could you answer the questions or have a Dwolla developer answer those -- most of the questions were on GetSatisfaction.

Both REgistering a user, REcurring payment streams and creating a Bank account and verifying it is critical for most of the types of transactions this community seems to be interested in - vis'avis' a single FORM UX process stream.  These have been default ACH endpoints for a long time now.  I am not sure why veridian isn't opening these up and creating less friction for Dwolla to create a ZERO friction user experience API for your 3rd party developers.

Thank you for answering our questions in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no API support for recurring payments, and I'm not sure if Dwolla plans to add it.

You may be able to do what you're hoping to via a regularly scheduled call to the API of the [request](https://www.dwolla.com/oauth/rest/transactions/request) method with the user's Dwolla ID or phone number, as documented [here](http://developers.dwolla.com/dev/docs/transactions/request). The user will still have to "pay their bill" each time, but will be prompted to do so with a Dwolla request for funds.

Comment: Thanks for the word Eric - are you with Dwolla?

Comment: Nope, just a fan! 

[Michael Schonfeld](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1408983/michael-schonfeld) been working pretty heavily on their API, though, so he's definitely the final word on it.